# Не могу вынести данные из fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook

В общем есть страница Left и компонент с функцией SearchFilms так вот проблема в том что не могу вытащить результат и fetch, и отобразить его на странице left, апи ключа убрал специально. Я новичок, поэтому хз как и что делать.

```
import React, {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Container, TextField, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";
import SearchFilms from "../companents/searchFilm";

export const Left = () =>{
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState ('')
    console.log(setKeyword)
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    console.log(setPage)
    function  handleSearch(e) {
        setKeyword(e.target.value)
        setPage(1)
    }
    SearchFilms(keyword, page)

    return(
        <Fragment>
            <Container fixed style={{paddingTop: "9%"}}>
                <form className="" noValidate autoComplete="off">
                    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Поиск" variant="outlined" onChange={handleSearch}/>
                </form>

            </Container>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Typography} from "@material-ui/core";


export default function SearchFilms(keyword, page)  {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-KEY': '17d4a3d9-ab7d-4038-843b-8a95e22b6c7b'
        }
        fetch(`https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.1/films/search-by-keyword?keyword=${keyword}&page=${page}`, {method:'GET',headers:headers})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setData())
    }, [keyword, page])
    return (
        <div>{data}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `then(data => setData(data))`?

Comment: @entithat я это делал в консоли выводится, а как вывести в функции Left я не знаю, когда map использую он пишет что data не определена(красным подчеркнуто)

Comment: передать как props в Компонент left и мапом вывести там?

Comment: @Armen сделал по другому немного)

Answer (score 0):

Может так, и убрать функцию SearchFilm?

```
  const Left = () => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [list, setList] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-API-KEY': '17d4a3d9-ab7d-4038-843b-8a95e22b6c7b'
    }
    fetch(`https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.1/films/search-by-keyword?keyword=${keyword}&page=${page}`, { method: 'GET', headers: headers })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setList(data.films))
  }, [keyword, page])
  function handleSearch(e) {
    setKeyword(e.target.value)
    setPage(1)
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Container fixed style={{ paddingTop: "9%" }}>
        <div>
          {list.map((el) => <div>{el.nameRu}</div>)}
        </div>
        <form className="" noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Поиск" variant="outlined" onChange={handleSearch} />
        </form>

      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: сделал иначе немного)